# D7 Rules - User Profile Field in Send Email Action

Tags: 7, rules

I'm using D7 with Rules 7.x-2.7. I am trying to create a Rule that will email and BCC all users of a particular role when a node of a certain content type is created. I've added the event: `After saving new content of type...`, and the action: `Send mail to all users of a role`. What I'm now trying to do is pull in the user profile data to populate the email body. Something like:

```
Hi [user-field-firstname],

A new announcement has been released. Please log in to your profile and browse to http://examplesite.com/user/[user-id]/announcements.

regards
```

I've been unsuccessful thus far. I've tried to add another action of `Fetch entity by Id`, but could find any decent selectors in the data selector. Any advice for me, please?

Comment: Have you tried the replacement patterns present in the Rules action page while creating the rules?
Check the image
http://drupal.cocomore.com/sites/default/files/blog_photos/drupal-rules-site_admin_email_notifications/drupal7-configure-message-new-user-4.png

Comment: I certainly have. But the only tokens I can see are those relating to `site` and `node`

Comment: Go ahead with Rules token but user object should be available by default. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: **Solved** please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!!!**

After breaking my head for a full day on this, I remembered something I read on a blog a while back about using views in Rules. So here goes and I hope this helps someone.

1. Download and enable the [Drupal Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) (`drush dl views_rules`)
2. Configure and customize a new view with a `Rules` display as below:

   [image]

   with the `row variables` configured similar to:

   [image]
3. Back in Rules, you will now see a new `Add view loop` method which can then be used as follows:

   [image]

I really hope this helps someone else. Note that I'm not using the Rules Tokens or Profile2 modules - just the Views Rules module. :)

Answer (score 0):

I might try the [Rules Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/rule_tokens) module (if you haven't already). It might contain what you need